# Why useWatch in an antd form can not access nested form items

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

How can i access the "name" in the form item? It only works without <Form.List>.

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, InputNumber, Typography } from "antd";
const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const nameValue = Form.useWatch("name", form);
  return (
    <>
      <Form form={form} layout="vertical" autoComplete="off">
        <Form.List>
          <Form.Item name="name" label="Name (Watch to trigger rerender)">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="age" label="Age (Not Watch)">
            <InputNumber />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form.List>
      </Form>

      <Typography>
        <pre>Name Value: {nameValue}</pre>
      </Typography>
    </>
  );

};
export default Demo;
```

[Here ist the code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-chatterjee-8wgm25)

Comment: First thing, you are not creating the `Form.List` correctly. Please follow this example to understand how you can create `Form.List` in antd [Form List](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item). You need to specify the `name` to `Form.List`. 
Then you need to understand how antd `NamePath` works, then you can get the correct value.